# unable to filter using get method(httpClient) in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to filter in service but not getting filter the data getting from URL.
Below is my code `

```
getCustomerList(_archid): void {
this.httpClient.get<ICustomer[]>(this.API_URL)
.subscribe(data => {
this.dataChange.next(data.filter(element => element.cat_type ==_archid));
console.log(data);
},
(error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
console.log (error.name + ' ' + error.message);
});
}
```

`Below is my ICustomer interface`

```
export interface ICustomer {
  id:number;
  cat_type:string;
  CustomerName: string;
 }
```

`
_archid is a string having the value "test" and below is my json getting from service

`

```
[
{"id":"2","cat_type":"test","CustomerName": "Accenture"},
{"id":"3","cat_type":"security","CustomerName": },
{"id":"4","cat_type":"test","CustomerName": "TCS"},
{"id":"5","cat_type":"test","CustomerName": "CTS"},
{"id":"6","cat_type":"newarch","CustomerName": "WIPRO"},
{"id":"7","cat_type":"colloboration","CustomerName": "Infosys"}
]
```

`

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. `data` is of type `ICustomer[]`, so it's an array, and arrays don't have a `cat_type` property. They have a length, that's all. Tell us what your method is supposed to do.

Comment: I just want to filter caty_type having type it. like below [
  {"id":"2","cat_type":"it","CustomerName": "tech1"},
  {"id":"3","cat_type":"it","CustomerName": "tech10"}
]

Comment: So you want to emit an array containing only some elements of the original array? You need to call filter on the array then, not on the observable: `.subscribe(array => 
      this.dataChange.next(array.filter(element => element.cat_type ===_archid)))`

Comment: exacty, but it's not working and error also not showing.

Comment: Define "not working", precisely. Update your question with the new code, a console.log showing what you receive, a console.log showing what archid is, a console.log showing the result of the filtering.

Comment: Sure, Below is my code, error's not showing.   getCustomerList(_archid): void {
this.httpClient.get<ICustomer[]>(this.API_URL)
.subscribe(data => {
this.dataChange.next(data.filter(element => element.cat_type ===_archid));
},
(error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
console.log (error.name + ' ' + error.message);
});
}

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: It's my bad, it's working like a charm. Thanks Nizet. Below code working shared by Nizet "this.dataChange.next(data.filter(element => element.cat_type ==_archid));
"

Comment: mention as answer, i will mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
.filter(data=>data.cat_type==_archid)
```

in this point data is type of ICustomer[] right?
so array doesn't contain cat_type right?

```
 getCustomerList(_archid): void {
this.httpClient.get<ICustomer[]>(this.API_URL)
  // .filter(data=>data.filter(x=>x.cat_type) ==_archid )
  .subscribe(data => {
    data.filter(x=>x.cat_type == _archid)
  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log (error.name + ' ' + error.message);
  });
```

}

in this line

```
data.filter(x=>x.cat_type == _archid)
```

x is a type of ICustomer so it will filter hot data.

[i am very new to this angular thing. so this is just my research]